# Turning some columns of data into rows, based on the content of specific cells

Tags: excel, google-sheets, rows

I have multiple rows of students on a spreadsheet and their grades across the top as column headers. Not all students do every subject I have listed so therefore some columns will be blank. I am trying to use these grades as a range and have the populated cells appear all next to each other at the end of the spreadsheet. I will hen need the subject header to come with the non-blank cells data.

See the screenshot below to understand what data needs to go where:

[image: Annotated version:]

I found a kind of answer on stack but its totally the wrong way round to how I have to work (see the image below). So, please help me flip this around so names would go down column A and subjects along the first row. (This is in a Google Sheet).

Lee

[image: Array Formula]

Here is a mock up of what I am trying to achieve, all data will likely be on one student row, but I have organised like this for the screenshot.

[image: Mock Up]

Comment: What is the answer you found? hard for us to modify it if we don't know what it is. Also, can you post some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Hi, it should be on the image I posted..?

Comment: As text would be more useful, and it's not clear (at least to me) from the screen capture what your source data is

Comment: What’s the best way of copying in excel/sheets data?

Comment: @Fennomenon - Perhaps drop a screenshot into your question?

Comment: Sorry I’ve not posted here before. I thought I had done a screenshot, can it not be seen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your annotated screenshot, here's how to get from the top table to the bottom table.

Put your `Subject 1`, etc. headings in manually.

Put `={G13:G16}` into `G20` to copy your student names.

In `H20` use `=INDEX(FILTER($H$12:$O$12, $H13:$O13 <> ""), 1, 1)` to grab the  first heading in `$H$12:$O$12` that is over a non-blank cell in `$H13:$O13`.

In the above formula, `FILTER()` grabs all the headings over non-blank cells in the range, while `INDEX()` is used to grab the first result.

Repeat the formula for `H21:H23` (letting Sheets update the references that aren't fixed with a `$` prefix.)

In `I20` use `=INDEX(FILTER($H13:$O13, $H13:$O13 <> ""), 1, 1)` to grab the first non-blank value in `$H13:$O13`.

Repeat the formula for `I20:I23`.

Moving right, just copy the formulas, but update the values for `INDEX()` but increase the column argument by one. eg. `J20` would contain `=INDEX(FILTER($H$12:$O$12, $H13:$O13 <> ""), 1, 2)` and `K20` would contain `=INDEX(FILTER($H13:$O13, $H13:$O13 <> ""), 1, 2)`.

This should get you well on your way.

Happy spreadsheeting!

Comment: Hi, thank you. Not sure I could transpose it that way. I have added a screenshot of a mock up of what I am trying for.

Comment: Thanks @Fennomenon, that's helpful. Can you share an annotated screenshot or an anonymized copy of the sheet you are starting from? The end state seems clear, but I can't see enough about where you are starting from.

Comment: I have used arrows in the original post to show you where I want the data to go. I have also copied it to this editable sheet, you'll see my successful attempts at doing it vertically, but I want the complete opposite! Thanks https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14AK7o4z_xbB7QUZuEkWPEpfqvG5Wd9n88PkKbr8Tewo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Those arrows make all the difference. :)